# Class Cast Exception starting on a certain KeyEvent

Tags: java, debugging, classcastexception

*Still improving on the same game as one of my older questions, only this time I now have four classes and another exception error. Still same "Java is 2nd language, still can't seem to prove my intermediate C++ sticker."*

Briefer: Making game in span of 2-2.5 years, have to do it in language I don't know because of majority rule in our team (three java, one C++, 1 php guy). I am testing mechanics with this "mini" game and trying to fix things that break but this(among others) is **another problem I can't seem to figure out on my own.** **I tried forums and have skimmed** through some of our old **self teaching java books.**

**I need help on how do I fix this situation of Class cast Exception.**

My code and provided explanations of what should be occurring briefly:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Stage extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Timer start_stop;
private SPRITES player;
public Stage()
{
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    player = new SPRITES();

    start_stop = new Timer(5, this);
    start_stop.start();

}

public void paint(Graphics character)
{
    super.paint(character);

    Graphics2D G2D = (Graphics2D) character;
    G2D.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    character.dispose();

      for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++ ) 
      {
            SPRITES m = (SPRITES) ms.get(i); //error here
            G2D.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getX(), m.getY(), this);

            if(m.isVisible())
                m.move();
            else ms.remove(i);
      }
      }

      public void actionPerformedjuan(ActionEvent e) 
      {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) 
            {
                SPRITES m = (SPRITES) ms.get(i);
                if (m.isVisible()) 
                    m.move();
                else ms.remove(i);  
            }
      player.move();
      repaint();
      }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    player.move();
    repaint();
}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter
{
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        player.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        player.keyPressed(e);
    }
}
}
```

Sets the stage, gets the background colored and gets the imported pictures ready.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SPRITES extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static int x_sped;
private static int y_sped;
private static int x;
private static int y;
private Image sprite;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static ArrayList missiles;
private final static int sprite_size = 20;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public SPRITES()
{
    ImageIcon pine = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resouse/SHIP.png")); 
    sprite = pine.getImage();
    missiles = new ArrayList();
    x = 40;
    y = 60;
}

public void move()
{
    x += x_sped;
    y += y_sped;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

public Image getImage()
{
     return sprite;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public ArrayList getMissiles()
 {
        return missiles;
 }
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void fire() 
{
    missiles.add(new Mussiles(x + sprite_size, y + sprite_size/2));
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        fire();
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        x_sped = -1;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        x_sped = 2;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        y_sped = -1;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        y_sped = 1;
    }


}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        x_sped = 0;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        x_sped = 0;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        y_sped = 0;
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        y_sped = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Makes my movements and imports the picture. As well it also is supposed to make my missiles fire from the ship with the space key, or at least set up the structure of the idea.

```
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Mussiles 
{
private int x, y;
private Image missile;
boolean visible;

private final int width = 30;
private final int missile_sped = 2;

public Mussiles(int x, int y)
{
    ImageIcon pine = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resouse/missile.png"));
    missile = pine.getImage();
    visible = true;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
}

public Image getImage()
{
    return missile;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

public boolean isVisible()
{
    return visible;
}

public void move()
{
    x += missile_sped;
    if(x > width)
        visible = false;
}
}
```

Imports the missile and makes it unseen the moment it's not directly on screen.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Framing extends JFrame
{
public Framing()
{
    add(new Stage());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Failing Mini Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        new Framing();  
}
}
```

Ties all the classes together to make it all work.

**Where I get the problem is when I press the space button to fire. It just spams the console with errors, if I read the eclipse backtrace right it leads to here in the first class shown:**

> ```
>           SPRITES m = (SPRITES) ms.get(i); //error here
> ```

As far as I know, it's because I'm importing an non-extended or implemented object. This is where I'm lost on how do I go about fixing this problem. **Do I put this general area of code in another class or is there a smarter way to fix this problem?**

I would also like to know if anyone knows a good almost layman easy guide to debugging, I haven't heard of any that are detailed on explanation but not too terribly mind numbing on detail.

Comment: `public class Mussiles {` ... this is not a type of `SPRITES`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public class Mussiles {` ... this is not a type of `SPRITES`, but you add it to your `missiles` `ArrayList`,

```
missiles.add(new Mussiles(x + sprite_size, y + sprite_size/2));
```

This is the cause of the `ClassCastException` because it's not possible for `Mussiles` to be treated like an instance of `SPRITES`.

First, make sure that `Mussiles` extends from `SPRITES`, then update the `ArrayList` to be confined to allowing only types of `SPRITES`

```
private static ArrayList<SPRITES> missiles;
```

(nb: You should avoid `static` for instance classes, they will only cause you problems)

This will also mean you can get rid of `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`, which you really should avoid, cause the compiler is trying to warn about the potential issue that you have just run into...

Also update your methods to reflect this confinement...

```
public ArrayList<SPRITES> getMissiles() {
    //...
```

This will also mean you won't need to blindly case values, because the type will now be more tightly defined...

```
ArrayList<SPRITES> ms = player.getMissiles();

for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) 
{
    SPRITES m = ms.get(i);
```

Take a look at the [Generics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details

Comment: Sorry if I sound more than incompetent, but after I've fixed my Arraylist, what do I do with this line of code?                                                `missiles.add(new Mussiles(x + sprite_size, y + sprite_size/2));`

Comment: Nothing, so long as `Mussiles` extends `SPRITES` and `missiles` is confined to only contain `SPRITES` it should work just fine...

Comment: Ah, thanks for providing an explanation as to where I went wrong, I also seem to remember you helped with the JLabel. On a side note: I seemed to programmed this wrong even after it worked. I can't see my missile fire and I made the space bar put me back in the spawn point. But this is somethign I can tackle at least.

Comment: From my "limited" experience in these things, it looks like you're going about it the wrong way.  You should have a centralised component which managers the inputs (key/mouse) and painting/updating of your entities.  You should have a "game-loop" which checks the inputs, updates the state and schedules the rendering.  The key events would then (probably) be passed to the entities so that they can make decisions about what to do.  New entities should probably be added into the game model directly.  But that's just a really "rough" concept...

Comment: I most likely I am not doing this the way it should be executed, but I haven't found many good books on proper game structure using Java. I'm probably not looking hard enough, but I'm assuming from your bio,  that you may know of any good books on this kind of topic? Most I tend to find focus on applets, which aren't more of my kind of thing.

Comment: I don't know about gaming books for Java, but basic game design and principles are generally the same across the board (more or less), get input, process input, update state, render output.  You could also take a look at something like [Game Development StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for other ideas

Comment: While this question is semi-relevant still, is it worth switching from swing to javaFX, is it faster? Or would it be better to attempt to convince my peers of going to C++ for optimization, (this is a presumption)bigger library to pick from, and a nice IDE(i've yet to find a Java IDE thats as easy to use and looks as great as Visual Studio, which saddens me a bit.)

Comment: It's debatable.  JavaFX may be better geared towards game development, FX8 is suppose to have/be getting support for 3D (haven't looked into), but Swing already has a number of game libraries, both at the 2D and 3D levels.  C++ would be faster then both and probably has a wider range of available libraries. Much is about personal opinion.  Swing has a larger, more experienced community then FX, so getting help might be easier.  As to VS, the last time I used it, I found it wanting, but that's because I'm use to other things, so it all comes down to what your use to :P

Comment: The reality is, the basic concepts won't really change between Swing, FX or C++, how you implement them will.  For example, generic support has been available in C++ long before Java got it ;)

Comment: The only thing is getting the basic concepts down pat, haha. I feel like I've used up enough of your time, but I now think I should look out for an angry programming penguin with a sailor hat when I get horribly confused with swing again.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Mussiles` isn't a SPRITE.

Also, a normal `ArrayList` doesn't guarantee that you return a `SPRITE`. Try changing the declaration of it to `ArrayList<SPRITE>` so that it can ONLY hold SPRITE objects (and update other values accordingly) This is safer.